# nginx rewrite directive not working in my case and not even able to debug rule?

Tags: regex, nginx, web

Just few days back I started working on web development.I have to prepend a new string in existing url. I am using NGNIX configuration to handle this scenario.
I have to change URL from http://192.168.10.128/Media to http://192.168.10.128/XYZ/Media . For this I have written below regex configuration to handle my above stated case.

```
 location / {
    rewrite ^\/(.*)$ /XYZ/$1
  }
```

Moreover I also need to see is there any issue with above regex , so for that added some more configuration in the nginx. Unfortunately i am not getting any message in error.log

```
error_log    /tmp/error.log;
rewrite_log on;
```

Kindly suggest where I doing mistake.

Comment: You need to look at the access log - not the error log. And make sure that the location/rewrite rule does not match URIs that begin with `/XYZ`, otherwise you will get a loop.

Comment: @Richard-Smith Thank you for your comment . can you please advise ,how to write rewrite to satisfy my scenario.